# Persistence Unit Service starting multille times

Tags: maven, war, ejb-3.0, ear

I am having EAR project which contains 1 EJB 3.0 Project and 2 WAR Project. 
I have defined persistence.xml in my EJB project.

However when the application starts it starts persistence unit service 3 times. 
As per log on startup I can see

```
Starting Persistence Unit Service 'xyz-ear.ear/xyz-ejb-1_0_0-SNAPSHOT.jar#xyzUnit'
Starting Persistence Unit Service 'xyz-ear.ear/xyz-war-1_0_0-SNAPSHOT.war#xyzUnit'
Starting Persistence Unit Service 'xyz-ear.ear/xyz-service-war-1_0_0-SNAPSHOT.war#xyzUnit'
```

Beacuse of this my database schema validation is happening 3 times.

```
@Startup
@Singleton
@PostConstruct
```

is getting called 3 times.

Has anyone faced this issue before? 
Please let me know if you need any other info.

PS: I have declared the EJB as ejb and not as ejb-client in pom.xml of both war module.

Can that cause this issue ?

Comment: Can you please check if you have your `xyz-ejb-1_0_0-SNAPSHOT.jar` also on your WARs WEB-INF/lib folder?

Comment: Yes, it's there in WEB-INF/lib folder. Currently in my WAR's pom.xml I have declared ejb's type as ejb.

Comment: That's why you are getting those three persistence unit indications. since you're already packaging your WARs and EJB in a EAR, there's no need for you to also have the EJB in your WARs' WEB-INF/lib. Mark the EJB dependency as `<scope>provided</scope>` on your WARs.

Comment: That worked perfectly. but when I made the ejb to <provided>true</provided> I am getting class cast exception "java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81 cannot be cast to com.xyz.abc.remote.AuthService" This is a remote call to EJB which is deployed in another server. I am not able to figure out the cause for remote ejb call to fail when I put provided for war pom.xml. Also this remote call is happening from EAR ejb module.

Comment: Glad it worked. The error you're now receiving is probably due to the way you're looking up your EJB. I suggest you to open a new question regarding this particular matter.