# Remote EJB Lookup to JBoss 5 from EJB Deployed in JBoss 6 + java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81

Tags: maven, ejb-3.1, jboss6.x

I have an EAR project which has an EJB module and a WAR module.

From EJB Module, when I do remote JNDI lookup to external EJB, which is deployed in JBoss 5, I get class cast exception. The error is shown below:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81 cannot be cast to com.test.abc.remote.IAuthService
    com.test.abc.util.ServiceLocator.getIAServiceRef(ServiceLocator.java:84)
```

The lookup returns the proxy object however the casting fails to remote interface.

The JNDI name which I am using is for remote lookup.

The strange behavior, which I have noticed, is that when I remove the scope provided the remote lookup is working fine.

From war/pom.xml (test-ejb is my local EJB deployed in jboss 6 through which I am doing remote lookup)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.dummy</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-ejb</artifactId>
    <version>${pom.version}</version>
    <type>ejb</type>
    <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
    <classifier>client</classifier>
</dependency>
```

WAR is deployed in EAR project itself.

Has anybody faced this issue before?

I'm using JBoss EAP 6 as application server and EJB 3.1.

The present post references [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759110/persistence-unit-service-starting-multille-times) post.

Comment: So, from my understanding of your problem, it as nothing to do with the external lookup of the EJB deployed on JBoss 5, am I right? What's failing is the local lookup, from the WAR module to the EJB module, within the EAR, correct?

Comment: Nope, the local lookup is fine, external lookup is failing. I have class ServiceLocator which is in my EJB(test-ejb). ServiceLocator does external lookup and fails with class cast exception. When i comment out <!-- <scope>provided</scope> --> section in my WAR module for test-ejb dependency. The external lookup works fine.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the EJB lookup that's failing?